# A second bachelor degree or a master in US?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, application, career-path

I graduated from a Canadian university 5 years ago in Electrical Engineering. My dream is to pursue a phD in Computer Science. However, the courses of my study is quite different from that in CS. I'm thinking about two paths in the following:

1. Apply for a second degree in CS in Canada. Comparing to graduate-level courses which requires strong foundations in CS, this will make me easier to attain a decent GPA. There will be longer time for me to intern in research institute and get papers published.
2. A master program will definitely save time. However, I will need to hand in my application for a phd just 1 year after entering the master program. I don't think I will make myself enough qualified just within 1 year, let alone that I lack the foundations in both Math and CS. A master in US is also always course-based in comparison to those thesis-based masters in Canada, which I am totally ineligible to apply due to different undergraduate discipline.

How about your advice? I appreciate any comment. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK there are thesis based masters in the US too, and many universities have a common department for both EE and CS.

Comment: Yes, there absolutely are research master's degrees (with a thesis) in CS in the United States.